# Ffmpeg video overlay enable between/gte only works with times and not frames

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I am trying to overlay one video on top of another, at a specific time (either between two times or after one time). I had previously been doing this with enable='between(t,2,4)' (or gte) for example, but when I needed to place another overlay directly after it I would sometimes get a one frame gap in between them. Because of this I decided to switch to specifying the frames with enable='between(n,60,120)', which works well with other types of overlays but not videos. When the overlay comes at the start of the main video, it works fine, however when the overlay starts later on, nothing appears. The following command works perfectly, with the overlay video coming in a 5.779 seconds and staying until the end.

```
/opt/ffmpeg -loglevel error -y \
-ss 3.56 -t 7.860 -i "main_video.mp4" \
-ss 1.5 -i "overlay_video.mp4" \
-i "overlay_image.png" \
-filter_complex "\
[0:v:0] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [0_p]; \
[1:v:0] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+5.779/TB [1_p]; \
[0_p] [1_p] overlay=y=0:x=0:enable='gte(t,5.779)':shortest=1 [0_p_o]; \
[0_p_o] [2:0] overlay=y=0:x=0 [0_p_o_o]; \
[0_p_o_o] drawbox=x=38:y=460:w=492:h=116:t=fill:color=#000000@0.7:enable='between(n,0,173)' 
[0_p_o_o_b]" \
-framerate 29.97 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vsync 2 \
-video_track_timescale 90000 \
-map "[0_p_o_o_b]" -t 7.860 "output.mp4"
```

However this command does not work, and the only change is the enable='gte(n,173)' instead of enable='gte(t,5.779)'

```
/opt/ffmpeg -loglevel error -y \
-ss 3.56 -t 7.860 -i "main_video.mp4" \
-ss 1.5 -i "overlay_video.mp4" \
-i "overlay_image.png" \
-filter_complex "\
[0:v:0] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [0_p]; \
[1:v:0] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+5.779/TB [1_p]; \
[0_p] [1_p] overlay=y=0:x=0:enable='gte(n,173)':shortest=1 [0_p_o]; \
[0_p_o] [2:0] overlay=y=0:x=0 [0_p_o_o]; \
[0_p_o_o] drawbox=x=38:y=460:w=492:h=116:t=fill:color=#000000@0.7:enable='between(n,0,173)' 
[0_p_o_o_b]" \
-framerate 29.97 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vsync 2 \
-video_track_timescale 90000 \
-map "[0_p_o_o_b]" -t 7.860 "output.mp4"
```

My guess is that it has to do with the PTS, and I tried playing around with the setpts on the overlay video but the best I was able to achieve was displaying the last frame of the overlay video for the duration of its appearance on screen, or one frame flashing up at 5.779 seconds and nothing more.

Could this be a bug in Ffmpeg? Or is there something else I need to do to get the overlay filter to work when specifying frames instead of times? Could the videos having different timescales affect things?

Comment: 1) Make the simplest command that still shows the problem, such as `ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -filter_complex "[1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+2/TB[fg];[0][fg]overlay=enable='gte(n,50)'" output.mp4`. 2) Show the complete log from the new [minimal, reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 3) You're already using `setpts` to delay timestamps. Are you sure you even need to use `enable`? 4) Avoid [crossposting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69388174/).

Comment: The above example omits some things that are important and could have an effect on the output, such as the -ss for both inputs. Can you get an overlay to display on top of another video only after frame number 173 using setpts alone?